# Netbeans shows compilation error in removed code

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors

i'm using netbeans IDE. the error was caused due to a variable i created in that method. but i deleted that method including its variables as you can see.

[image]

i removed that method. i tried to comment out that line but it still shows error. i'm new and i'll appreciate if you explain what's wrong here or its a bug in my IDE because i haven't seen anything like it before. when i hover my cursor on bulb and click it doesn't do or show anything.

Comment: Have you tried to save the file?

Comment: You may need to save the changes and re-compile your code.

Comment: yes i tried saving and clean build but it doesn't help.

Comment: thank you @AndiCover it really worked. didn't know i just have to close and re-open my project and haven't seen that one before

Answer (score 1):

Just reopen the file and see if the error is still there.
It can happen that Netbeans does not show you the correct error.

Comment: this answer is useful but i cannot mark because my reputation is less than 15. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If we can see the whole code of that class, it would be more helpful to analyze the error.

First thing comes in my mind like these errors is a syntax error. Check that if you mistakenly commented a `{` or `}` so that a bracket is opened but didn't closed.

Also try to clean the project and build again.